# What's the right time to call Context.getSystemService?

Tags: android

I write some code like this:

```
mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

It will run in Application's `onCreate` function. But in some Android phones , it will be crashed in construct function of `AudioManager`. I found someone else had this problem , he said it should be called within `onCreate`, that's what I do exactly.

**So my question is what's the right time to call getSystemService? Or my usage of it is totally wrong?**

Logcat:
[image]

Comment: `onCreate(...)` is right place to call but you must check your `context != null`

Comment: @MD I got crash in AudioManager's construct function, so the context should not be null.

Comment: ohhhh then you should post your logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `Context` methods in `onCreate()` or later in the component's lifecycle.

The stacktrace you posted shows you're calling `getSystemService()` in `ApkDownloadInfoDataManager.<init>` i.e. constructor or member variable initialization. It is too early, assuming that `ApkDownloadInfoDataManager` is-a `Context` and you're calling a method on it. Other reasons for the problem there include an invalid `Context`, such as one instantiated with `new`.